# Error with curl uploading file to .NET MultipartFileStreamProvider

Tags: .net, curl, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload a file to a .NET application using with cURL.  My command line is something like

```
curl -F "FormVar=@filename" http://...
```

When I do that, I get an error like this:

```
System.IO.IOException: Error writing MIME multipart body part to output stream. 
---> System.InvalidOperationException: The stream provider of type 
'CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider' threw an exception. ---> 
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not determine a valid local file 
name for the multipart body part. 
---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path, Boolean 
checkAdditional)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFileName(String path)
   at System.Net.Http.MultipartFileStreamProvider.GetStream(HttpContent 
parent, HttpContentHeaders headers)
```

What I noticed is that `curl` wraps the filename in quotes in the HTTP Content-Disposition header:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FormVar"; filename="MyFilename.txt"
```

If I capture the broken request in Fiddler, manually delete the quotes around `MyFilename.txt`, and replay the request, it

How do I get `MultipartFileStreamProvider` not to break if the filename contains quotes?

The quotes are part of the [standard for the Content-Disposition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) header; note "RFC 2616 only allows "quoted-string" for the filename parameter"

Comment: I have the same problem and ended up with using `.Trim('"')`. Nobody has an idea why this happens?

Comment: Working as intended. Ocaso's solution is ideal.

Comment: @Davesoft why is it working as intended?  If `filename="quoted"` is standard, why should that break by default?

Comment: Different contexts. One context demands 'a thing' and in another context you have 'a thing, possibly in a box'. It is intentional that the possible-box needs to be handled by you, the only thing linking those 2 contexts.

Comment: I am thinking of the `Trim` solution as a workaround, but it seems like the MultipartFileStreamProvider should solve for that natively.  If quoted filenames are permitted by the RFC standard then it shouldn't require custom code to not break.

Comment: Feel free to contact 'them' and state your demands. Till then, trim or maybe 'js eval' it :)